# Difference between Redis (key/value database) and an associative array?

Tags: php, database, arrays, nosql, redis

Redis is a NOSQL key/value database, which reads the entire life within RAM (and thus is quite fast). To me, an array (e.g., in PHP) does the same, as an array is a set of key/value. The main difference of a database is that indexed values will be called individually without reading the entire database.

Now when Redis read the entire database (into RAM), how it is different from an array of key/value?

Comment: It is still a **persistent** storage available **via network**

Answer (score 11, accepted):

- One Redis can serve multiple servers across the **network**
- As a consequence of the previous point, it supports **authentication**
- A Redis dataset can be **persisted** to disk
- Redis can work as a **queue** with blocking reads
- Redis supports **multiple DBs**
- Redis can automatically **expire a key** after a certain timeout or at a certain time
- Redis can provide a **list of all requests** in real time
- Redis allows to **subscribe** to certain events
- Redis supports **replication** to another Redis server
- Redis supports **multiple languages**, you're not tied to a single one

Comment: Yes, these are advantages of a DB server, but an array is also persisted to disk and we can have multiple DBs (arrays). Am I right?

Comment: yes, you can serialize and persist an array to disk, and you can have multiple arrays of course.

Comment: Don't forget sets, sorted sets, hashes, etc..  Redis is not only key-value. Redis is more if a data structure server than a simple database server.

Answer (score 0):

Also note that memory usage in PHP is very bad for arrays. So if you have a large array you will need a lot of memory. Redis can do it more efficient.

Comment: I have noticed this but have no theoretical explanation for this. Is it the case for Perl and Python too ?

Comment: In PHP each element requires a value structure (zval) which takes 16 bytes. Also requires a hash bucket - which takes 36 bytes. That gives 52 bytes per value. Memory allocation headers take another 8 bytes*2 - which gives 68 bytes. (https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=41053). I don't know about Perl and Python.

Comment: @Ali in Perl I don't know, but is easy to find out with [Devel::Size](http://search.cpan.org/~nwclark/Devel-Size-0.77/lib/Devel/Size.pm) package. To import: use Devel::Size qw(total_size);